# php vlookup in sql

Tags: xml-parsing, vlookup

I have a table like this in sql

```
  ID  NAME  SIZE  GROUP1  GROUP2   SIZE2
   1   casa   xl    1        2        
   2   casa    l    1        2
```

I'd like to obtain a table like this

```
     ID  NAME  SIZE  GROUP1  GROUP2   SIZE2
     1   casa   xl    1        2         l
     2   casa    l    1        2         xl
```

So the value of GROUP1 and GROUP2 identify the id that have similar NAME but different value for size
 Ho can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Join in the same table again, with the id that is not the same as the record itself:

```
select
  t.ID, t.NAME, t.SIZE, t.GROUP1, t.GROUP2, t2.SIZE
from
  TheTable t
  inner join TheTable t2 on t2.ID = case t.GROUP1 when t.ID then t.GROUP2 else t.GROUP1 end
```

To select from table1 and insert it into table2:

```
insert into table2
select
  t.ID, t.NAME, t.SIZE, t.GROUP1, t.GROUP2, t2.SIZE
from
  table1 t
  inner join table1 t2 on t2.ID = case t.GROUP1 when t.ID then t.GROUP2 else t.GROUP1 end
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply I create a table1 with value and a table2 without value and I tried to use this code
select
  table1.ID, table1.NAME, table1.SIZE, table1.GROUP1, table1.GROUP2, table1.SIZE2
from
  table1
  inner join table2 on table2.ID = case table1.GROUP1 when ID then table1.GROUP2 else table1.GROUP1 end";

that you passed me....but it doesn't work

Comment: @user2120473: My example shows how to query a single table to get the result. If you join in a different table, that won't work.

Comment: Hi guffa sorry I think I misunderstand...I must create only one table that I call table 1 for example and not another table (table2) where put the new result?

Comment: @user2120473: Then just add `insert into table2` before the query in the anwer.

Comment: @user2120473: You can select data from any tables and insert in one table using the syntax `insert into sometable select ...anything...`

Comment: ok...but where I must modify table1 and table2 in your code? could please you repost it? for me it would be better do it in 2 table

Comment: @user2120473:  I pasted it together above.

Comment: @user2120473: Could you be more specific? What happens when you try to use it? Do you get any error message?

Comment: hi guffa no the file works fine no error, but the table 2 is empty

Comment: @user2120473: Then just run the `select` without the `insert` to see that you get the correct result from that part.

Comment: @user2120473: What do you mean? The query only reads from table1, so table2 is irrelevant for that part. You need something in table1 for the query to return anything.

Comment: yes my table1 is like the first table I post but when I do the query nothing happens

Comment: @user2120473: "Nothing" very rarely happens... I suppose that you mean that you get an empty result back. Do you use only `table1` in the query? In the code that you posted before you used `table1` and `table2`.

Comment: no i take the second code you post and delete the first line and test....but empty result as you say

Comment: @user2120473: I corrected `ID` to `t.ID` in the query, and then it returns the expected result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b910/2

Comment: Hi guffa you're a geniuos:-)!it works perfect!a last question...if I have more than a group for example 7 group (group1, graoup2, group3....) and 7 size (size1, size2,size3....) how i must modify your code?

Comment: @user2120473: Then you would need a `case` with one condition for each field. Having multiple fields like that makes the data hard to query, you should try to normalise the data so that you get the group associations in a separate table.

Comment: so this is may case. I've a tag in a xml called GROPPRODUCT that has the value of all id with that name but different size
I nedd to have only an id with all the size

Comment: @user2120473: I don't understand your description at all.

Comment: ok this is my tag in xml <groupproduct>200,201,800,801</groupproduct>. That number are the ids of one product (for example a dress) byt with different value only for the tag SIZE (m,s,xl etc....). SO in my xml if, for example I have one dress with 4 different avaible size, i'll will try in the xml 4 products with all tags equal and only the tag size different. I'd like to put in my sql only one row with the four size

Comment: @user2120473: I have to repeat that storing multiple values like that in a single record is not practical. If you do that, it will be complicated to query, as you need to handle each value separately. It get even more complicated if the number of sizes can vary, because then you have to handle unused fields also.